# Can't find any way to call lastReadMessageIndex Method

Tags: twilio-conversations

I'm developing an endpoint in my nodeJs backend project and I can't find any way to call the lasReadMessageIndex Method.

I read the horizon documentation and there says:

> The same lastReadMessageIndex is also available from the REST API and can also be changed from your backend service.

But it doesn't mention where is this API which route should I call.

Anyone could help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Within the Conversations REST API, the `last_read_message_index` and the `last_read_timestamp` would be available on the Conversation Participant Resource (and the multi-service version as well).

You would be able to fetch this value or update these values for each participant, directly from the REST API.

Conversation Participant Resource: https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-participant-resource

Multi-service Conversation Participant Resource: https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/service-participant-resource

Read-Horizon documentation reference: [https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/read-horizon#:~:text=a%20Message.%0A%0AThe-,same,-lastReadMessageIndex%20is%20also](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/read-horizon#:%7E:text=a%20Message.%0A%0AThe-,same,-lastReadMessageIndex%20is%20also)